# Typo3 - Extension "news" - Set number of posts per page

Tags: typo3

Im using the extension "news" in a TYPO3 4.7 System. I have a working List view, and I want to use pagination to show 8 posts per page. The default is 10, and I don't know how to customize this.

there is a field "Max records displayed" but this just limits the total number of Posts in total, not "per page"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
paginate.itemsPerPage
```

?

I looked that up on http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Main/Configuration/Reference/Index.html

Comment: Yes, that is right. But where can I change the value of itemsPerPage in the backend?

Comment: You mean in the flexform - probably that's not been put in, as happens with many extensions to prevent the plugin flexforms from becoming bloated. Do you really need your customer to modify that value? Else, you can set it individually in the Backend via TS wherever you want.